# I want to summarize a huge data frame in R in such a way that I only need unique "lat", "lon", "Date (Year)" and "Maxium Value"

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate, data-manipulation

I need to summarize a huge CSV file (nrow =1102300). This is daily climate data from various climatic models.

First, I want to sum up all the columns with  "historical" names. My target is the maximum values filtered by Date (in Year Year (i.e. 1950, 1951, etc ) for all the unique "lat" and "lon."

All help will be appreciated.

The dataframe is like this:

```r
df = read.csv(text = '"lat","lon","Date","pr_CMCC.ESM2_historical","pr_GFDL.ESM4_historical_ssp126","pr_BCC.CSM2.MR_historical_ssp126","pr_INM.CM4.8_historical_ssp126","pr_FGOALS.g3_historical_ssp126","pr_TaiESM1_historical_ssp126","pr_NorESM2.MM_historical_ssp126","pr_CanESM5_historical_ssp126","pr_KIOST.ESM_historical_ssp126","pr_NorESM2.LM_historical_ssp126","pr_INM.CM5.0_historical_ssp126"
46.29166646,-62.62500314,1/1/1950 12:00,1.7243347,6.10E-05,6.10E-05,2.5483093,1.7853699,6.10E-05,1.846405,6.10E-05,1.4954529,1.4496765,3.769043
46.29166646,-62.62500314,1/2/1950 12:00,6.10E-05,6.10E-05,6.10E-05,9.24704,6.10E-05,12.741333,6.10E-05,6.424103,0.56463623,6.10E-05,1.1139832
46.29166646,-62.62500314,1/3/1950 12:00,6.10E-05,6.10E-05,6.10E-05,6.10E-05,6.10E-05,1.052948,6.10E-05,1.1445007,6.10E-05,6.10E-05,6.10E-05
46.29166646,-62.62500314,1/4/1950 12:00,7.965271,6.10E-05,6.10E-05,6.5919495,1.9684753,6.10E-05,6.10E-05,1.4191589,6.10E-05,0.70196533,3.9368896',header = TRUE)
```

I want my final output dataframe arrainged like this:

```
lat | lon | Value
```

Where Value = Maximum value for each year.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your expected output given this sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```r
df |>
  mutate(
    Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),
    Year = format(Date, format = "%Y")
  ) |>
  summarize(
    .by = c("lon", "lat", "Year"),
    Value = max(rowSums(pick(matches("historical"))))
  )
#       lon      lat Year    Value
# 1 -62.625 46.29167 1950 30.09146
```

This assumes that your `lon` and `lat` are relatively invariant, though even with that sometimes grouping by floating point numbers may be problematic (see [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272) and https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). I suggest that if the rest of your data has any variance in `lon` and `lat` for each year, then there are likely different things you should be doing to aggregate your data.

---

The use of `.by=` requires `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer; if you have an older version, change from `summarize(.by=c(..), stuff)` to `group_by(..) |> summarize(stuff) |> ungroup()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked close to what I want. Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse) # presumes tidyverse 2.0+ so includes dplyr 1.1.0+ for ".by"
                   # and lubridate included with tidyverse load
df |>
  pivot_longer(contains("historical")) |>
  mutate(yr = year(mdy_hm(Date))) |>
  summarize(value = max(value), .by = c(lat, lon, yr))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
    lat   lon    yr value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  46.3 -62.6  1950  12.7
```